# Call method with enum parameter and Eval in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, eval

I have this method on page class

```
public string GetTranslations(UITranslations uiTranslation)
        {
           return ((AppUICulture)Application["UICulture"]).GetTranlsation(uiTranslation);
        }
```

And I want to populate placeholder with string like

```
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="inpLogId" type="text" placeholder='<%# GetTranslations( UITranslations.LOGIN_ID ) %>' required>
```

Where `UITranslations` is an `enum`.

How do I properly use `Eval` to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Eval you need to create binding context. One of the easiest options would be to use FormView. Here is sample:

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <input runat="server" class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="inpLogId" placeholder='<%# this.GetTranslations( UITranslations.LOGIN_ID) %>' />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```